# AppCompatActivity openOptionsMenu not working

Tags: android, button, menu, onclick

I updated my question, since I solved one part, but the tricky one is still pending :
I have an `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` 
with fragments
I deleted the ActionBar and put a small height LinearLayout as follows. I want an ImageButton to open the OptionsMenu. when the `onClick` is called, why the `openOptionsMenu();` is not called. I mean the Options Menu does not appear.
While it does appear when I click on the Menu hardware button of the emulator.

Thanks for your kind help
below, find relevent part of the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/tx_notdone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tv_progress"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="139dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pb_simulation"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:max="100" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:id="@+id/btmenuImg"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

```
ImageButton imgbtmenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btmenuImg);
    imgbtmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
```

...

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        // debug
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_saveparam) {
        saveparam();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_loadparam) {
        // debug
        loadparam();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':MPChartLib')
```

}

I also found something describing a bug
[Issue 185217:  openOptionsMenu() does not show menu when inheriting from AppCompatActivity](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185217)

Tried

```
    @Override
public void openOptionsMenu() {
    // Based loosely on http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/app/WindowDecorActionBar.java#getDecorToolbar
    final Window window = getWindow();
    final View decor = window.getDecorView();
    final View view = decor.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
    if (view instanceof Toolbar) {
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view;
        toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.
The Fabric button works fine and also another button on the fragment.
The fragment implements a onTouch method (that works fine) to interact with an image that it displays.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research and tries, the only way is to simulate a KeyEvent. 
This makes the options menu appears

```
        BaseInputConnection  mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection( findViewById(R.id.main_content), true);
    KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
    KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
    mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(kd);
    mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(ku);
```

Comment: What is main_content here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are using toolbar

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
                }
            }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to open up the options menu. But I ended up just using PopupMenu in the end...

Java:

```
@Override
public void openOptionsMenu() {
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        BaseInputConnection  mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(v, true);
        KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
        KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
        mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(kd);
        mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(ku);
}
```

Kotlin:

```
override fun openOptionsMenu() {
        val v: View = this.window.decorView.rootView
        val mInputConnection = BaseInputConnection(v, true)
        val kd = KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        val ku = KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(kd)
        mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(ku)
    }
```